# Horizontal listbox aspx

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, controls

What is ASPX control can provide a behavior of the Outlook "To" control, it apply to choose multiple items and display it horizontaly, ListBox is enough for me but I couldn`t find a way to change the items orientation to horizontal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the information horizontally, you could use a [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx) control and then set the [RepeatDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx) property to *Horizontal*.

```
<asp:DataList id="ItemsList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        { whatever you want to display here } 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```